# Reactjs backend connection issue

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux, react-router

My problem is that my browser is showing that fire store is not able to connect to the backend:

```
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.1.1): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Permission denied on resource project MY_PROJECT_ID.
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
```

My firebase.js code is

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";
import "firebase/compat/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: MY_API_KEY,
  authDomain: MY_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: MY_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: MY_STORAGE_BUCKET_URL,
  messagingSenderId: MY_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: MY_APP_IP,
  measurementId: MY_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
const storage = firebase.storage();

export { auth, provider, storage };
export default db;
```

Please help me .

Answer (score 1):

New firebase v(9.1.1) is modular based version. Therefore you have to import everything as named import from respective files.
eg:-

```js
import {  initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'
```

```js
const firebase = initializeApp({
  apiKey: MY_API_KEY,
  authDomain: MY_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: MY_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: MY_STORAGE_BUCKET_URL,
  messagingSenderId: MY_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: MY_APP_IP,
  measurementId: MY_MEASUREMENT_ID,  
 })
 
 const firestore = getFirestore()
```

The method/function way of using firebase is not supported in v(9.1.1), this probably helps with tree shaking(loading only required files/functions, rather than entire library), which saves loading time and creates fast user experience.

For detailed information checkout these videos:-[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BjtxPj6jRM8&ab_channel=Firebase)

Also check firebase docs:-[enter link description here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to generate a new `firebaseConfig` file? You can do that by

1. Going to your project settings.
2. At the bottom of the page there's a section called `Your apps`.
3. On the top right of that section click the button labeled `Add App`.
4. Choose the icon for webapp (3rd from the left).
5. After choosing a name for the new webapp, you'll get your new `fbconfig`.
6. Copy new `fbconfig` to your project and try again.

Let me know what happens please.

EDIT 0 -

[image]

Comment: actually that config is one of my friends `fbconfig` that i am using he told me that i can use it in my project and i am not having his account details

Comment: So you couldn't generate the new fbConfig? It could be that you have a mistake in the fbConfig somewhere. You need to check that you have copied it exactly. I mean it could just be that he removed this fbConfig from his project.

Comment: my friends config db contains some data that i do not have

Comment: Do you want to start your own firebase project? I think it'll be easier for you than to rely on a project you don't have access to. It's very easy to start your own project. If your friend wants to give you access to his project he can add you as an editor or a viewer. He can do that by going to users and permissions in the image in my answer

Comment: is there any other way

Comment: If you don't even have access to the firebase console, how are you supposed to see if everything is in order? What other way could anyone give you?

Comment: now i have got access to it and the project is working now